# When using React Native FlatList there comes space between rows when the content length differs and there are more than 1 columns. Any fix for this?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-ui-components

[This is the flatlist layout with numColumns={2[The FlatList component[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VTWH.png)}][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPvbX.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.